Get WooCommerce product attribute name value from its slug in the current context
I am building a custom table for products, I am attempting to add both simple products and variations to the same table. I have done this so far but I need to modify the title for variation products. I am attempting to do this format:
"Product Title
Black, 8 in."
I have this code:
foreach ($available_variations as $variation) { 
            //$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            $new_attributes = $variation['attributes'];
            $data_array = array();
            $allowed_attr = ['pa_color', 'pa_gauge', 'pa_size', 'pa_dimensions', 'pa_quantity', 'pa_length', 'pa_material'];
            foreach ( $new_attributes as $meta_key => $meta ) {
                $attr_label   = wc_attribute_label( $meta_key, $product );
                $attr_value = $product->get_attribute($meta_key);
                array_push($data_array, $meta);
            }
            
            $attribute_sub = implode( ', ', $data_array );

This gets close to the desired format when echoed. It ends with:
"Product Title
24-black, 8-in"
I can only use the variation object in the current context, is there any function I can use that would only take the attribute group slug and the attribute value to get the Attribute label?
Something that might work like this:
get_attribute_lable("24-black", "pa_color"); --> Returns "Black"
I've attempted to use wc_attribute_label but it seems it only works with the attribute group. get_taxonomy also only gets the group from what I've attempted. If I do need to write a custom function what would be the quickest without having to open an SQL query?

I modified your code to use the get_term_by function, which fetches the human-readable attribute term based on the attribute's slug and taxonomy. This allows you to retrieve the correct label for each attribute value and format it in the desired way. The wc_attribute_label still retrieves the attribute group label (e.g., "Color"), but by combining it with get_term_by, we get the specific term name, allowing you to properly format your variation titles like "Product Title Black, 8 in." without needing to perform SQL queries. hope it helps...
foreach ($available_variations as $variation) { 
    //$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    $new_attributes = $variation['attributes'];
    $data_array = array();
    $allowed_attr = ['pa_color', 'pa_gauge', 'pa_size', 'pa_dimensions', 'pa_quantity', 'pa_length', 'pa_material'];
    
    foreach ( $new_attributes as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
        // Get the attribute label (like "Color", "Size", etc.)
        $attr_label = wc_attribute_label( $meta_key, $product );
        
        // Get the term label for the attribute value (like "Black", "8 in.")
        $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta_value, $meta_key);
        if ($term) {
            // Add the term name (like "Black") to the data array
            $data_array[] = $term->name;
        }
    }

    // Now we can implode the array to get the attribute sub-string
    $attribute_sub = implode( ', ', $data_array );
    
    // Example: Echo product title with attribute values appended
    echo $variation['variation_title'] . ' ' . $attribute_sub; //It should Outputs: "Product Title Black, 8 in."
}


Thank you! I thought I was missing something with the term. I tried this and unfortunately it is blank. I echoed the $term to double check and it isn't returning anything. No error codes or anything like that.
